# server side validation in typescript - .net core app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have .NET Core app with Angular and I want to perform a server side validation from TypeScript.

To be specific, there is a button on the screen that should only trigger an action if certain fields on this screen have valid values (I need to check this values (from model) with values from database)), so I need to call a server side action.

I am not performing POST/PUT actions while clicking the button. Fields have to be filled-in, but I am not processing them. When some obligatory fields are filled in and values are valid, I want to open a pop-up window by clicking the button. And betweent this typescript actions i need to perform serverside action

What is the best way to achive that?

Comment: Without performing request, it is impossible to process server side validation.

Comment: I want to perform a request, but Im not performing request using fields on The screen. My question is How to call this serwer side event? Create controller called „ValidationController” And call it from Tyoescript And then consume received value? Is it a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly broad question, and there are many different ways of going about server side validation.

[This article](https://www.puzzle.ch/de/blog/articles/2017/01/18/server-side-validations-with-angular-2) gives a general overview of server side validation with an angular2 app with Rails, but a similar approach for a .NET core app should work.

Namely, you should have an error handler in your POST/PUT to the server that looks for a 422 (or other error code), and sets the client side field errors appropriately. The server code needs to check the POSTed values for validity (which will include any database calls/etc) and be responsible for setting the 422 or another error code on the response back to the client.

Comment: I am not performing POST/PUT actions while clicking the button. Fields have to be filled-in, but I am not processing them. When fields are filled and values are valid, I want to open a pop-up window by clicking the button